# No Items return from JS graph call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a line in my SPFx web part code like this:

```
const listItems = await client.api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields.get();
```

In my DEV 365 it brings all the items in the list.
In my Prod 365 I have the same lists and items but the call brings NO items without throwing any error.
I test the call in Graph Explorer and it brings all the items as expected with the same user.
What can be the issue here?

Comment: First i would make sure you have enough permission in Prod 365. To validate it would try the same API call in Graph explorer (i see you did that its working) and checking checking the token/scope/permissions. As you said it works in Graph explorer, that means no issues with the Graph API call. In such scenario, just validate whether you're using the same AAD workflow that you're using as well (when compared to Graph explorer); if not, try testing the same in POSTMAN and see if it helps you to isolate the issue further.

Comment: Graph explorer ran as me and so the JS. Turns out it was missing Sites.Read.All right at the API level. But why didn't I get an error?

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it doesn't thrown any error at app level, then i would have check the code, how implementation been done, exception handling etc. If i want to debug further, i would have enable custom telemetry logging of request/response logs or run tools like fiddler to see whats happenning there.

Comment: Let me move this to answer. So it can be useful to others. Please feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

- First i would make sure you have enough permission in Prod 365.
- To validate it would try the same API call in Graph explorer (i see
  you did that its working) and checking checking the
  token/scope/permissions. As you said it works in Graph explorer, that
  means no issues with the Graph API call. In such scenario, just
  validate whether you're using the same AAD workflow that you're using
  as well (when compared to Graph explorer); if not, try testing the
  same in POSTMAN and see if it helps you to isolate the issue further
- You confirmed that Graph explorer ran as me and so the JS. So it turns out it was missing Sites.Read.All right at the API level.